# Google Map not centreing on location when geolocation is disabled

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a problem where if geolocation is disabled then the map should centre on a specified location, but nothing is being loaded when it is disabled. The first part of the `if` statement works fine when geolocation is enabled. Why isn't the `else` part working when it is disabled?

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) { 
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;                    
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;               
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapOptions = 
    {
      zoom: 15,  
      center: coords, 
      mapTypeControl: true, 
      navigationControlOptions:
      {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL 
      },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById(''));
    var request = {
      origin: coords,
      destination: 'BT42 1FL',
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  });
}
else {
  alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");
  var mapOptions =
  {
    zoom: 15,  
    center: 'BT42 1FL',
    mapTypeControl: true, 
    navigationControlOptions:
    {
      style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL 
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions);
}
```

The `alert` doesn't alert either.

Comment: Check the value of navigator.geolocation, is it being set properly?

Comment: Don't you have a debugger?

Comment: The file that this code is in is linked into a file that is then included into my `index` page. How can you debug an included file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome 24 at least, when geolocation is denied by the user `navigator.geolocation` is not falsy.

If the user denies geolocation, the *failure* callback (the second argument to [`getCurrentPosition`](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#get-current-position)) will be called.  This will also happen of course for any other failure to get the location.  Play around with the following code (available in [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgDRk/)):

```
function success() {
    alert("success!");
}

function failure() {
    alert("failure!");
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, failure);
    alert("truthy!");
} else {
  alert("falsy!");
}
```

On my browser, if I click the "deny" button this alerts "truthy" followed by "failure".  If you want to give the same behaviour regardless of whether geolocation failed or the user rejected it, I'd suggest code like the following:

```
function noGeoInfo() {
    alert("couldn't get your location info; making my best guess!");
}

function geoInfo(position) {
    alert("hey your position is " + position + " isn't that swell?");
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoInfo, noGeoInfo);
} else {
    noGeoInfo();
}
```

Comment: So how can I get it to carry out the `else` section of the statement?

Comment: @Colin747 on closer examination it looks like I must have messed up the tests.  It does call the failure callback (the second argument to `getCurrentPosition`), so I would implement that as a function, and both pass it to getCurrentPosition as a callback and execute it from the else branch.  Editing my answer to match that.

Comment: Sorry can you explain why on the jsfiddle if I disable geo-location the alert says `truthy` then another alert says `failure`?

Comment: Sure. I'll try to think like a browser developer when explaining it.  When you eval `navigator.geolocation` you're basically asking "does this browser support geolocation?" and this one does, so the `if` statement executes the `then` block rather than the `else block`, calling `getCurrentPosition` and then the `alert("truthy!")`.  Now when we called `getCurrentPosition` we provided 2 functions: one to be called if we get the position (`success`) and one if we can't (`failure`). When `getCurrentPosition` tries to get the position it finds it doesn't have permission, so it calls `failure`.

Comment: If you're confused about the order of events, I don't blame you, and would suggest you research the nature of "javascript callbacks".

Comment: So it alerts `truthy` as the browser supports geolocation and then alerts `failure` as I have it disabled?

Comment: Thanks, you've been a great help.